# Pass codeception test name to browserstack

Tags: codeception, browserstack

I want to pass my test names to browserstack, so that they are logged in the session value (name) within the browserstack interface

In my Acceptance helper I have the following method defined

```
 /**
 * HOOK: before test
 *
 * We use this method to set the test name which will be logged in BrowserStack
 * https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities
 * @param \Codeception\TestInterface $test
 */
public function _before(\Codeception\TestInterface $test)
{
    codecept_debug('_before');
    codecept_debug($this->getModule('WebDriver')->_getConfig()['capabilities']);

    $config['capabilities'] = $this->getModule('WebDriver')->_getConfig()['capabilities'];
    $config['capabilities']['name'] = $test->getName();
    $this->getModule('WebDriver')->_setConfig($config);  

    codecept_debug($this->getModule('WebDriver')->_getConfig()['capabilities']);
}
```

There are a few issues with my approach

1. This event seems to fire after the test is logged in browserstack (which is my main issue - I'm looking for the right place to inject this name value)
2. The tests would sometimes be logged under the wrong names - several tests will use the same name

Which event should I use to achieve my goals?

Answer (score -1):

Looking through codeception and in particular webdriver source code, I saw this:
https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/2.5/src/Codeception/Module/WebDriver.php#L394

````
 /**
 * Change capabilities of WebDriver. Should be executed before starting a new browser session.
 * This method expects a function to be passed which returns array or [WebDriver Desired Capabilities](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/community/lib/Remote/DesiredCapabilities.php) object.
 * Additional [Chrome options](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/wiki/ChromeOptions) (like adding extensions) can be passed as well.
 *
 * ```php
 * <?php // in helper
 * public function _before(TestInterface $test)
 * {
 *     $this->getModule('WebDriver')->_capabilities(function($currentCapabilities) {
 *         // or new \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities();
 *         return \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities::firefox();
 *     });
 * }
 * ```
 *
 * to make this work load `\Helper\Acceptance` before `WebDriver` in `acceptance.suite.yml`:
 *
 * ```yaml
 * modules:
 *     enabled:
 *         - \Helper\Acceptance
 *         - WebDriver
 * ```
 *
 * For instance, [**BrowserStack** cloud service](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities) may require a test name to be set in capabilities.
 * This is how it can be done via `_capabilities` method from `Helper\Acceptance`:
 *
 * ```php
 * <?php // inside Helper\Acceptance
 * public function _before(TestInterface $test)
 * {
 *      $name = $test->getMetadata()->getName();
 *      $this->getModule('WebDriver')->_capabilities(function($currentCapabilities) use ($name) {
 *          $currentCapabilities['name'] = $name;
 *          return $currentCapabilities;
 *      });
 * }
 * ```
 * In this case, please ensure that `\Helper\Acceptance` is loaded before WebDriver so new capabilities could be applied.
````

This seems to produce the same bugs as my original question in that,

1. Some tests don't have their names set
2. Some tests have the name of the previous test set

EDIT: 
The reason the above was happening, was because in my environment file/definition of the device there was a declaration of

```
 modules:
  enabled:
   - WebDriver
```

Removing the enabled and webdriver definition allows the fall back on the acceptance.suite.yml which then works correctly as intended